# How can I use 'addChildEventListener()' accurately for following purpose?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data stored in `FirebaseDatabase`.

Here's what data-structure look like:

```
app
 -ref
   -requestID
     -key
       -key: value
       -key: value
       -key: value
```

Here's how I'm trying to retrieve data using `addChildEventListener()`:

```
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://app-q24sg.firebaseio.com/ref");

    ref.child(requestID).child(key).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                  Log.d("dataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
              } else {
              }
    }
    ...
    ...
});
```

The `Log.d` here is printing out:

```
D/dataSnapshot: value
D/dataSnapshot: value
D/dataSnapshot: value
```

I tried `Log.d("dataSnapshot", dataSnapshot.getKey());` but then I got:

```
D/dataSnapshot: key
D/dataSnapshot: key
D/dataSnapshot: key
```

What I want is:

```
{key=value, key=value, key=value}
```

so that I can do this:

```
final Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
key1 = map.get("key");
key2 = map.get("key");
```

I know I can use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `addValueEventListener` for achieving what I want but I don't want the piece of code to run every time `onDataChange()` is called and that I can only achieve by adding code in `onChildAdded()` (or not?).

**So, how can I** use `addChildEventListener()` here to get the required results?

Comment: when do you want this string `{key=value, key=value, key=value}` ? is it for every `onChildAdded` (so the returned string will be incremental for each `onChildAdded` method call) ? or any other event? please explain.

Comment: @Wilik yes, a child is added under `requestID` so this: `{key=value, key=value, key=value}` is required for every `onChildAdded`.

Comment: please respond.. I have asked a new related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42469250/6144372

Answer (score 1):

If you want the datas like `{key=value, key=value, key=value}`, get only `.child(requestID)` without `.child(key)` with `.addValueEventListener`. It returns whole node. Then cast it to a hashmap, `((HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue())`. Get the specific value with `((HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue()).get(key)`.

But you want create `Hashmap` with `addChildEventListener()`. Create a `Hashmap` before the `addChildEventListener()` then fill it in `onChildAdded`,

```
final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
ref.child(requestID).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                      map.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getValue());
              } else {
              }
    }
    ...
    ...
});
```

Comment: after doing this: 
`map.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getValue());` can I do this: 
`key1 = map.get("key");
key2 = map.get("key");`??

Comment: NO, after `map.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),dataSnapshot.getValue());` doing this `Log.d("key", map.get("key").toString());` crashes the app giving `nullpointerexception`.

Comment: I don't see reason to you can't do it. Maybe there  is no data under your path and  `dataSnapshot.getValue()` returns `null`. And `addChildEventListener` is an async method, if you try to get map's value just below your `addChildEventListener` it can returns `null`. Try to get the data from map after you are sure that the answer is coming from the firebase. @HammadNasir

Comment: well, I tried this: `Log.d("map", map.toString());` and got `D/key: value` printed out so I'm sure it's not `null`. but doing `Log.d("key", map.get("key").toString());` is returning `null`.

Comment: Are you sure that the key you put in your map is the same as the key you use to call? Did you check it in debug mode? @HammadNasir

Comment: i think i got the problem... the data from firebase is getting added one by one in the map so when I try to query for a specific key, this key hasn't been added yet to the map! How can I make sure that all the data should get added at once?

Comment: Yes, `addChildEventListener()` brings the data one by one. So I told you to create it outside of `addChildEventListener()` and fill it in method. As i say if you want the all data at once use `.addValueEventListener` without `.child(key)`

Comment: I have created it outside and then I'm populating it inside. Even then the data is getting added one by one. How to add the data all at once here itself?

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42469250/6144372 I have asked a new question on this issue.