# How to add all data at once in a HashMap under addChildEventListener() of Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, hashmap, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data at a certain reference in Firebase and I'm retrieving it using `addChildEventListener()` and putting it in a `HashMap<String, Object>` like this:

```
final HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
ref.child(requestID).child(key).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
              if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                  map1.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getValue());
                  Log.d("map1", map1.toString());
              } else {
              }
    }
    ...
    ...
});
```

**The problem** is that the data is getting added one-by-one and `Log.d` is printing out:

```
D/map1: {key=value}
D/map1: {key=value, key=value}
D/map1: {key=value, key=value, key=value}
D/map1: {key=value, key=value, key=value, key=value}
D/map1: {key=value, key=value, key=value, key=value, key=value}
```

**What I want** is to put this data into `map1` all at once and get this
`D/map1: {key=value, key=value, key=value, key=value, key=value}` printed out.

I want to use `addChildEventListener()` only as I want to run the piece of code only when `onChildAdded()` and not every time `onDataChange()`.

**Please help me** figure this out.

Comment: You might want to look at [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-database/9242/reading-data/28682/understanding-which-data-is-inside-datasnapshot-object#t=201702261440327477941)

Comment: @koceeng I didn't get it... can't you just help me figure out my solution, please?

Comment: @koceeng I read your documentation and tried another way around and got another issue. Please help with it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42476569/6144372

Comment: @koceeng please help with it.. it is according to your docs now.

Answer (score 1):

A `ChildEventListener` is triggered for each individual child. That is a great interface if you're doing something like updating the user interface, because you can know exactly what to do: `onChildAdded` -> add UI element, `onChildChanged` -> update UI element, etc.

If you want to get all matching elements in one go, you should use a `ValueEventListener`:

```
ref.child(requestID).child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
          for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              map1.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue());
          }
          Log.d("map1", map1.toString());
      }
```

Comment: There must be someway.. I can't use 'valueEventListener()' as I don't want to make the piece of code execute if any data has changed.. i want it to execute once the data has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a very clean solution to exactly what you are trying to achieve. You want to get all the data at once instead of one by one, but what happens when you get a new child? You will get it one  by one.

You could do something like this which would theoretically give you the entire hashmap at once, but for any subsequent children added, they too will be added one by one. You will have to use ValueEventListener, only once however, and move your old code inside it's onDataChange.

```
    reference.child(requestID).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long startChildCount = dataSnapshot.exists() ? dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() : 0;
            int i = 0;
            HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<>();
            ArrayList<DataSnapshot> tempSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
            reference.child(requestID).child(key).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    i++;
                    if (i < childCount) {
                        tempSnapshots.add(dataSnapshot);
                    } else if (i == childCount) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : tempSnapshots) {
                            map1.put(snapshot.getKey(), snapshot.getValue());
                        }
                    } else {
                        map1.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.getValue());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Okay, I tried using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and got into an issue. Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42476569/6144372

Comment: if you want to get data at once then you must have to use **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** instead of  **addChildEventListener**

because **addChildEventListener** will add one by one