# 'addListenerForSingleValueEvent' in populateViewHolder method of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter gets called whenever data changes under Firebase reference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-location, firebaseui

I'm using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` in my app and trying to populate it by fetching some data inside it's `populateViewHolder()` method and then assigning values to different parameters.

Here's my code:

```
private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        Query lastFifty = aReference.child(requestID).limitToFirst(50);
        mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AModelClass, AModelClass.ViewHolder>(
                AModelClass.class, R.layout.a_layout, AModelClass.ViewHolder.class, lastFifty) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final AModelClass.ViewHolder viewHolder, AModelClass model, int position) {
                final String key = this.getRef(position).getKey();
                aReference.child(requestID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {    
                            aReference.child(requestID).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("pName") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("pUrl") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("currentLat") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("currentLng")) {
                                            final Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                                            pA = map.get("pName");
                                            uidP = map.get("pUrl");
                                            nP.add(map.get("pName"));

                                            cLatPlayers.add(map.get("currentLat").trim());
                                            cLngPlayers.add(map.get("currentLng").trim());

                                            viewHolder.setPNameT(pA);
                                            viewHolder.setPicP(uidP);
                                            viewHolder.setCurrentLatAU(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
                                            viewHolder.setCurrentLngAU(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));

                                            addMarkers();

                                            layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                    }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no data available yet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        mRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
            }
        });

        aList.setAdapter(mRecyclerViewAdapter);
    }
```

`attachRecyclerViewAdapter()` is placed in `onCreate()`.

Here's `aList` initialisation in `onCreate()`:

```
aList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.aList);
aList.setLayoutManager(nLinearLayoutManager);
```

Here's `onLocationChanged()` method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        currentLtAU = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        currentLnAU = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

        aReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLatUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
        aReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLngUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));        
}
```

which saves updated lat and lng to database whenever location is changed under the same reference from where data is getting retrieved above.

The `LocationRequest` code:

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
}
```

Everything is working just fine here, the **only problem** is that the code under reference: `aReference.child(requestID).child(key)` or (`aReference.child(requestID)` maybe?) is getting called again and again (though it is supposed to be called just once because of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`), thus filling `nP`, `cLatPlayers`, `cLngPlayers` multiple times and also the `addMarkers()` method is getting called multiple times causing problem in the Map.

Why is this happening and **How can I** make sure that this doesn't gets called multiple times?

Comment: Your code is so confusing, inside `aReference.child(requestID)` there is another `aReference.child(requestID)` with `.child(whatever)`. That will make your code run multiple time, to be exact, it will run `aReference.child(requestID)` child's count ^ 2 times

Comment: @koceeng is it the cause of endless loop or does it makes the code run for some specified number of times?

Comment: You are the one who write that code, you tell us. I'm just analyzing and guessing. If `aReference.child(requestID)` has 5 child then `if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("pName") && dataSnapshot.hasChild("pUrl") ...etc` will run 25 times

Comment: @koceeng no, this is not the cause... the cause is that I'm saving updated location under the same reference and whenever it gets changed `onDataChange()` is triggered causing whole code inside it to run again... that's why I first asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42460780/6144372 and then this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42469250/6144372

Comment: @HammadNasir I don't think you can use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in this way. I suggest you to ditch FirebaseRecyclerAdapter and create your custom RecyclerAdapter. I've used custom RecyclerAdapter-addListenerForSingleValueEvent together and they've behaved as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came up with a very simple yet effective solution.

I just saved the updated locations at a different reference in database so that whenever it changes the `onDataChange()` under `aReference.child(requestID)` is not called and thus the code does not gets executed again and again.

I changed the code under `onLocationChanged()` from this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        currentLtAU = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        currentLnAU = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

        aReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLatUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
        aReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLngUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));        
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        currentLtAU = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        currentLnAU = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

        anotherReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLatUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLtAU));
        anotherReference.child(requestID).child(userID).child("currentLngUpdated").setValue(String.valueOf(currentLnAU));        
}
```

But I'm still unable to understand why `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` listens for data changes every time though it is supposed to listen data changes just once.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you're getting a loop then the problem is at the place where you change the values in response to the change.

So here:

```
viewHolder.setPNameT(pA);
```

Try doing something like:

```
if (!viewHolder.getPNameT().equals(pA)) {
    viewHolder.setPNameT(pA);
}
```

So only update the value if it's different and then it won't register as being changed and fire off another call to the listener. This way you only get one loop for each change.

I haven't used FirebaseRecylcerView (didn't know it existed until now) but this is the general approach I've used in the past for TextWatchers. It seems like the same problem.

Comment: I tried this but still I'm getting an endless loop... values from database is getting added in `ArrayList<>` again and again. :|